# I have a problem in the using of a struct in different files

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, include, typedef

I defined a structure in a file.c and I defined a typedef to his pointer in his header.
I want to use this typedef in another file.c but it doesnt work. I think that it is a problem with the include of the files.

**In the file game.c**

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "chessSystem.h"
#include "tournament.h"
#include "game.h"
#include "map.h"
#include "player.h"

struct Game_node
{
    int game_id;
    Game_data game_data;
    Game next;
};
```

In the file game.h I am doing:

```
typedef struct Game_Node *Game;
```

And I want to use this struct in another file: tournament.c Into a function I try to define a variable of the type Game. But I cant access to the fields of the struct.

```
#include "game.h"
..........

Game temp_game=malloc(sizeof(*temp_game));
    temp_game->
```

Important to signal that in the allocation of temp_game the IDE signal an error:Invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct Game_node'.

I know that is not very clear.
if you have questions tell me.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Move the struct definition from the C file to the header file.

Comment: Move the structure definition to the `.h` file where it belongs.  If it's not in the `.h` file, then *of course* other files can't see it.  Think about it.

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — TL;DR the answer is usually "No", with possible exceptions for function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The type definition `typedef struct Game_Node *Game;` refers to an incomplete type as the details of the structure `Game_Node` are not known. The compiler can still compile code that only uses pointers to `struct Game_Node` but not code that uses `sizeof(struct Game_Node)` or accesses members of this structure.

A common case is `FILE` often defined in `<stdio.h>` as an incomplete type. The various stream functions take a `FILE *` and user code does not need to know the details of the implementation, which varies a lot from on system to another.

You should move the structure definition from **game.c** to **game.h**.

If you want to restrict access to the structure internals, you could define it in a separate file **gamedef.h** only included in the appropriate modules.